# What does the ACF tell me here?

Tags: autocorrelation, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

I have a time series of monthly sales data that is incomplete. That is, the product was partly out of stock and the sales of those periods are too low.

I manually fixed this and wanted to plot the data and a forecast to see if my fixes are reasonable.

So I came across this easy to implement excel forecasting technique (http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411outbd.htm), that uses the "single-equation recursive form of Brown’s model". And the results do look plausible.

In this article the value of alpha is found by having excel minimize the RMSE. And for my data I get an alpha of 0,44214... With this value the plot looks good. But the ACF does not (I think). Here it is:

[image]

Varying alpha I can get this ACF to look better (according to my limited knowledge of what it should look like) but the forecast is way off then.

So what can you deduce from this ACF about the time series?

The time series (after my corrections) is this:

```
23,0
21,0
65,0
98,0
248,0
315,0
217,0
176,9
131,4
177,2
113,9
123,9
195,1
225,9
263,1
352,0
673,4
560,8
891,0
518,4
257,2
264,0
160,0
213,0
```

Comment: Is this a time series with just five or six values?

Comment: The time series has 24 months worth of data. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Also I may have mixed something up... and the image is not an ACF. It is called 'error autocorrelation' in the article. But the article only talks about why ITS 'error autocorrelation' is ok and not what makes it so.